# login: after entering user information, membership in the 0th index in the sql table is always displayed

Tags: c#

I want to make a registration and login system. It is possible to register, the user information is saved in the sql table, but if the user wants to log in, the user in the 0th index in the sql table seems to be logged in. I tried to bring the user information on the main screen with conditional sql commands, but for example, if I check the phone number and get the information, it still gets the phone number in the 0th index.

```
    //this is the code i am trying to get username to label
    MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select First_Name from ACCOUNTS where Phone_Number=@Phone_Number";
            command.Parameters.Add("@Phone_Number", PhoneNmb.Text);
            string ClientName= (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            //PhoneNmb.Text is login screens textbox.text

            label.Text = "Hoşgeldiniz " + ClientName;
            
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Accounts table data:

[image: ACCOUNTS TABLE DATA]

Accounts table view designer (ID SPECİFİCATİONS TRUE):

[image: ACCOUNTS TABLE VİEW DESİGNER (ID SPECİFİCATİONS TRUE)]

Comment: Can you please show the "Accounts" table ?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide formatted text for your table details, not images. Read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for more details about why this is very important.

Comment: Aside from formatted text: Please include more details, for others to help you. That includes any type of additional parameter detail, output, etc.